# Not onto, not one-to-one, and not bijection

Tags: combinatorics, functions

If there is a mapping of x to y, where more than one value of x can map to the same, and also not all the values of y have a mapping from x, is there a name for this sort of function? (note if not implied: x has less elements than y)

Comment: It's just a function. That isn't surjective nor injective. A function is what you are looking for. I don't know why your parenthetical remark is relevant.

Comment: I think you are just describing maps that are not injective (not one to one) nor surjective(not onto). I don't think there is name for describing both at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, there is no specific name for the functions that you describe. The classifications of surjectivity and injectivity are rather special conditions for a function to obey, and it makes sense that there may not be a specific way to denote that a function does not obey either property beyond just observing the complementary designation.

Along the same lines, given any two sets, the set of all functions between these two sets would mostly be comprised of these "generic" non-surjective, non-injective functions. (This excludes pathological edge cases, e.g. where there is only one element in both sets, in which case there is only one possible function, which is both injective and surjective.)

Answer (score 1):

I hereby dub such objects to be "non-injective, non-surjective functions."

Comment: ( +1 ) Second!!